# Why does ./startFabric.sh stop on joining channel without error in fabcar example?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have installed hyperledger fabric v1.4. All the tests with byfn went well. Now I'm trying to run fabcar example. So, I ran ./startFabric.sh and the scripts stop on the step :"# Join peer0.org1.example.com to the channel." in ./start.sh on basic network.

Before that, I had an error that one container wasn't running. So I reinstall docker-ce 18.09, and this error seems to be fixed.
I did not modify the docker-compose.yaml and all paths seems to be good.

I tried to increase FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT but it doesn't work.

This is the output:

```
# wait for Hyperledger Fabric to start
# incase of errors when running later commands, issue export FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT=<larger number>
export FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT=10
#echo ${FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT}
sleep ${FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT}

# Create the channel
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/channel.tx
2019-02-12 09:49:56.517 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2019-02-12 09:49:56.541 UTC [cli.common] readBlock -> INFO 002 Received block: 0
# Join peer0.org1.example.com to the channel.
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel join -b mychannel.block
2019-02-12 09:49:56.767 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized

erall@-GP73-Leopard-8RE:~/data/workspace/fabric-samples/fabcar $
```

This is startFabric.sh in fabcar directory:

```
# clean the keystore
rm -rf ./hfc-key-store

# launch network; create channel and join peer to channel
cd ../basic-network
./start.sh   

# Now launch the CLI container in order to install, instantiate chaincode
# and prime the ledger with our 10 cars
docker-compose -f ./docker-compose.yml up cli

docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" cli peer chaincode install -n fabcar -v 1.0 -p "$CC_SRC_PATH" -l "$CC_RUNTIME_LANGUAGE"
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" cli peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C mychannel -n fabcar -l "$CC_RUNTIME_LANGUAGE" -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":[]}' -P "OR ('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member')"
sleep 10
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" cli peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C mychannel -n fabcar -c '{"function":"initLedger","Args":[]}'
```

This is ./start.sh in basic-network :

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml down

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d ca.example.com orderer.example.com peer0.org1.example.com couchdb

# wait for Hyperledger Fabric to start
# incase of errors when running later commands, issue export FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT=<larger number>
export FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT=10
#echo ${FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT}
sleep ${FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT}

# Create the channel
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/channel.tx
# Join peer0.org1.example.com to the channel.
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel join -b mychannel.block
#end start script. (the script is exited on this command.)
```

This is where my script stops, i had any errors output, so I don't know what is going on. The rest of startFabric.sh is not executed so the chaincode is not installed.
I think that something fails on the block creation and it prevents the peer to join the channel.

Any idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was just the **'-d'** flag missing on running cli container :
`docker-compose -f ./docker-compose.yml -d up cli`

this solves my problem.