# [fabcar], After starting ./startFabric.sh, I have this error :Error response from daemon:container xxx is not running

Tags: ubuntu, hyperledger-fabric

I tried to start a fabcar problem in ubuntu, however I get the error and I don't know how to solve it.

I use ubuntu in Alibaba Cloud, and fabric's first-example was ok here.
When I used the fabcar, I found a error"

> Error response from daemon: Container
>   66f7dfd7117b8f9e36e937f646e9e865d600a235aa2c57dd9e0dfc7cfbebb753 is
>   not running

I have  already used `npm install fabric-client`and  `npm install fabric-ca-client`

```
root@iZ2zefth7vpdr5atlevkrjZ:~/hyperledger-fabric/fabric-samples/fabcar# ./startFabric.sh

# don't rewrite paths for Windows Git Bash users
export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml down
Removing network net_basic
WARNING: Network net_basic not found.

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d ca.example.com orderer.example.com peer0.org1.example.com couchdb
Creating network "net_basic" with the default driver
Creating orderer.example.com ... done
Creating couchdb             ... done
Creating ca.example.com      ... done
Creating peer0.org1.example.com ... done

# wait for Hyperledger Fabric to start
# incase of errors when running later commands, issue export FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT=<larger number>
export FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT=10
#echo ${FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT}
sleep ${FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT}

# Create the channel
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/channel.tx

Error response from daemon: Container 66f7dfd7117b8f9e36e937f646e9e865d600a235aa2c57dd9e0dfc7cfbebb753 is not running
```

I tried to reinstall the docker, it doesn't help.
I found new information about the error:
the `docker ps -a` showed

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                                        NAMES
66f7dfd7117b        hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start"        31 seconds ago      Exited (2) 29 seconds ago                                                peer0.org1.example.com
```

The program tried to start the container but exit.
what should I do to solve it?

Comment: I would redirect you to similar question as he was facing the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54647698/why-does-startfabric-sh-stop-on-joining-channel-without-error-in-fabcar-exampl

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help me,  I tried to reinstall the docker-ce, but no helps.

Comment: Same, any progress?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added your computer's username to docker group

Comment: I used root，how to add username to docker group? I am new here.

Comment: **sudo usermod -aG docker your-user** as per docker documentation [docker-debian](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/debian/)